# SHA512 not the same in CryptoJS and Closure

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library, sha512, cryptojs

I have some troubles with a simple crypto-challenge.

I want to do following:

- getting a url-encoded and base64-encoded value
- do url-decoding
- do base64-decoding
- hash with Sha512

When working with CryptoJS, i use following code:

```
var parameter = "Akuwnm2318kwioasdjlnmn";
var urlDecoded = decodeURIComponent(parameter);
var base64Decoded = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(urlDecoded);
var hashed = CryptoJS.SHA512(base64Decoded).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
//hashed = "UxupkI5+dkhUorQ+K3+Tqct1WNUkj3I6N76g82CbNQ0EAH/nWjqi9CW5Qec1vq/qakNIYeXeqiAPOVAVkzf9mA=="/eWTS2lUgCEe6NJDXhNfYvXMRQDvH6k2PHVmy6LJS7RloVvcQcpVjRNVU5lJpAg=="
```

When working with Closure, i use following code:

```
var parameter = "Akuwnm2318kwioasdjlnmn";
var urlDecoded = decodeURIComponent(parameter);
var byteArray = goog.crypt.base64.decodeStringToByteArray(urlDecoded);
var base64Decoded = goog.crypt.byteArrayToHex(byteArray);
var sha512 = new goog.crypt.Sha512();
sha512.update(base64Decoded);
var hashed = sha512.digest();
hashed = goog.crypt.byteArrayToHex(hashed);
//hashed = "bc2a878edfffb0937fbc6c0f9dbc9566edc59b74080d68d4c8bdfeb4027f17c4316a02285baaf446872d2df37b1144ac3ce18d62ab9c786b1f1fb18a53acea1d"
```

So, why are the hashes different?

I would be very happy if someone could tell me how to adapt the Closure-Code, to get the same hash as the CryptoJS code provides.

Thanks a lot!

PS:

I also tried:

```
var parameter = "Akuwnm2318kwioasdjlnmn";
var urlDecoded = decodeURIComponent(parameter);
var base64DecodedByteArray = goog.crypt.base64.decodeStringToByteArray(urlDecoded);
var sha512 = new goog.crypt.Sha512();
sha512.update(base64DecodedByteArray);
var hashed = sha512.digest();
hashed = goog.crypt.byteArrayToHex(hashed);
//hashed = "531ba9908e7e764854a2b43e2b7f93a9cb7558d5248f723a37bea0f3609b350d04007fe75a3aa2f425b941e735beafea6a434861e5deaa200f3950159337fd98"
```

but then, as you see, i get another hash. why??

Comment: Updated, because i mentioned that the parameter was a bad choice. Now, i even get three different hash values. Why??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first hash value is identical to the third, except it is base64-encoded rather than hex-encoded. You can change to hex encoding and get the same value:

```
var hashed = CryptoJS.SHA512(base64Decoded).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
//hashed = "531ba9908e7e764854a2b43e2b7f93a9cb7558d5248f723a37bea0f3609b350d04007fe75a3aa2f425b941e735beafea6a434861e5deaa200f3950159337fd98"
```

The second approach you show has a different value because you are not hashing the same data; you are instead converting the byteArray to a hex string and then hashing that string representation, not the underlying values.

Comment: how to execute the above statement in angular 2?