# How to generate sha512 in ionic 2 angular 2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I need to integrate payubizz payment gateway in ionic2 framework.

in this process I need to generate hash code by using product details. like

```
sha512(C0Dr8m|12345|10|Shopping|Test|test@test.com||abc||15|||||||3sf0jURk);
```

Please help me any one, thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you searching for? A library that can generate SHA512? or something else?

Comment: I had a library named  CryptoJS ,  but I don't know about how to import  CryptoJS  library and generate hash code by using sha-512, please help me.

Comment: Have you tried Forge? https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Answer (score 0):

Use CryptoJS which provides the libraries for hashing and encrypting

[This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25865222/4525473) might show a usage